# Networkmanager KDE5 plasma (Fedora 22)

Tags: fedora, kde, networkmanager

After upgrading to Fedora 22 (KDE5), I have trouble running (or actually editing connections) the Network Manager, namely `kde5-nm-connection-editor`.
I can click on my WiFi-Symbol, I can click the `editicon`, which opens the connection editor. But I literaly can't *edit* something with the *editor*.
The *okay*-Button is simply greyed out.

```
groups
wheel vboxusers network

sudo cat /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/50-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.rules
    polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
       if (action.id.indexOf("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.") == 0 &&  subject.isInGroup("network")) {
       return polkit.Result.YES;
      }
    });

ps aux | grep polk
polkitd    960  0.0  0.1 533252 15424 ?        Ssl  19:07   0:00 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
thomas    1761  0.0  0.4 664572 36320 ?        Sl   19:07   0:00 /usr/libexec/kf5/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1
```

Polkit seems to be running, and I am in the goup `network` and the rule should allow me to edit entries.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just bumped into the same issue with Fedora 22 running KDE5. OK button is still gray in `kde5-nm-connection-editor`.

"Solution" is to add new connection via `nm-connection-editor` application.